# The class or interface com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder could not be loaded

Tags: flash, jpeg, flash-cs5

I am a total Flash newbie. I just installed Flash CS5 and wrote the following code:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData
import flash.geom.Matrix
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

//get the default camera
//change your Default camera using the Flash Player Settings.
cam=Camera.get()
//this event is called whenever permission to access the local camera, is accepted or denied by the user
cam.onStatus=function(e)
{
    //if we are given permission
    if(e.code == "Camera.Unmuted")
    {
        //start the application
        initialize()
    }
    else
    {
        System.showSettings(3)
    }
}

var snapshot:BitmapData=new BitmapData(cam.width,cam.height);

function takeSnapshot()
{   
    var i:Number=1;
    var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
    snapshot.draw(cam,new Matrix());
    //saveImage();
     var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
     var ba:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);
     fileRef.save(ba,"capture"+i+".jpg");
     i++;
}


//if there are no Cameras
if(cam == null)
{
    System.showSettings(3)
}
else
{
    cam.setMode(1024, 768, 30);
    cam.setQuality(10000,0);
    output.attachVideo(cam);
    setInterval(this,"takeSnapshot",100);
}
```

On exporting to SWF, I am getting the error :

```
The class or interface com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder could not be loaded
```

I have downloaded the as3corelibrary from the right source from code.google.com and have placed the folder in the root. Right now it is C:\wamp\www\com\adobe\images\JPGEncoder.as

Is there some classpath or something that I have to set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've put the code for as3corelib in the root of the web server - you've to put the source in the root folder of your source path. Normally that's the same folder that has your FLA. Copy the `com` folder to the same folder that contains your FLA and then compile.

In case you've your FLA in the same folder (the root of the web server), that's a bad idea to begin with - everybody will be able to access your source code.

Comment: Oh yes I did put the as3corelib in my server's root. And the FLA file is somewhere else. I'll correct myself as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to set the classpath.

From [Adobe help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html#WSB1F410E6-F7BD-443a-97E7-13DE866CA732):

> To set the application-level source
>   path:
>
> 1. Choose Edit Preferences (Windows) or Flash > Preferences (Macintosh) and
>      click the ActionScript category.
> 2. Click the ActionScript 3.0 Settings button and add the path(s) to
>      the Source path list.

Comment: You mean add "C:\wamp\www\com\adobe\images\JPGEncoder.as" or just "C:\wamp\www\com\adobe\images" ?

Comment: You should add `C:\wamp\www`. The package `com.adobe.images` tells the compiler where to look for the classes.